# iOS ViewController property dissappears after pushing a new controller and coming back again in Navigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios

I couldnt find any thread for this problem, so thats why i ask you here.

I would be really happy if someone could help me.

I have got a navigation Controller, and I'm pushing TableViewController's into it. My problem is that, when i click on Back button, my previous tableViewcontroller appears with the previous data, but the dataArray property (datasource for my tables) is empty.

My code:

```
  @interface patientViewControllerSearch : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ASIHTTPRequestDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;
    NSMutableArray *letters;

    UITableView *tableView;
    IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) esTabBarController *esTabBarController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

In my patientViewControllerSearch i do in ViewDidLoad:

```
dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
letters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And with a HTTP request i fill my arrays.

Thats working fine.

After:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller                                         animated:YES];
```

When i come back, (viewDidload not loading again, thats why there is no new request for filling dataArray) dataArray, and everything is empty. The tableView shows my previous state, but after refreshing that dissapears too.

Have you got any advice?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason "viewDidLoad" is not being called is because it was already loaded the first time it appeared in your app (I assume on launch).

You will notice that "viewWillAppear" and "viewDidAppear" will always be called before/after the view presents itself in your application.

These would be the appropriate methods for you to use if you want to update your data when the view is shown to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But could you tell me why my array always dissappears? I would be happy, if that array could stay in the memory. I have an other controller written by an other guy, and there he makes a `data = [[[configManager sharedInstance].config objectForKey:@"institutionList"] retain];` in ViewDidLoad and the whole array stays in the memory when im navigating back.